# ReactJS - Single Page Application : Authentication screen navigation is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, single-page-application, react-router-dom

Trying to build a mini single page react app,

I have written following block of code to authenticate. I am expecting, when authentication succeeds, it would navigate to 'list' page, and when it fails, it would navigate to '/' (which is login/current screen). Using BrowserRouter to achieve this.

When executed, it always navigates to '/' (same page). And interestingly, '?' is getting appended to url.

```
handleClick = () => {
        auth.getToken(this.refs.username.value, this.refs.password.value)
        .then(this.props.history.push('/list'))
        .catch(this.props.history.push('/'));
    }
```

Kindly advise.

Comment: Is this on a button in a form? Is it possible you're triggering an actual page refresh? (What happens if you change `handleClick = () => {` to `handleClick = (e) => {` and add the line `e.preventDefault();` as the first line of the function?)

Comment: Or alternatively: add the prop `type='button'` to the  button this is on (if that's the case).

Comment: Perhaps this: `.then(() => this.props.history.push('/list'))` and then this: `.catch(() => this.props.history.push('/'))`. Right now your code is running before the promise is either resolved or rejected.

Comment: @SamVK, preventDefault() and prop type='button'  doesn't help.  Yes, button is part of form.

Comment: @Rodrigo, I have modified the code as per your suggestion. But it didn't help. Still catch is not navigating the screen to ('/')login page.

Comment: Can you modify that to .catch((err) => { console.log(err) }) and let us know what it says?

Comment: is `auth.getToken(...)` returning a `Promise`?